# Upload and download multiple files in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, 2012

Any ideas how to upload and download folder with multiple reports in SSRS 2012?

It's very dull to upload files one by one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Report Manager does not have a bulk upload/download feature , as you said you can only download/upload a report one by one.

Meanwhile, you can use **SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for visual Studio** for creating and managing Reporting Services reports solutions and projects.

**SQL Server Data Tools** provides the Report Designer authoring environment. In Report Designer, you can open, modify, preview, save, and deploy report definitions, shared data sources, shared datasets, and report parts.

Once you create a new solution you can add all current reports and their shared data sources, shared datasets and configure the `Target report server URL` and `Target Server Version` (in your case it's SQL Server 2012 version) to specify the location and version of the report server, the folders on the report server.

[image]

Now , you don't need to download reports (All reports in your solution) and you can deploy (bulk upload) all the reports or a specific report to report server easily.

To download SQL Server Data Tools check [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313)

For more details check

- [Reporting Services in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT-BI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173745(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [Publishing Reports to a Report Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159270(v=sql.110).aspx)